# Can you assign ggplot2 aestetics by calling characters in a vector?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have some R code that works great for analyzing and plotting data from a certain type of experiment, and I am optimizing it to require minimal user input. Unfortunately, I have hit a roadblock when I try to assign ggplot2 aesthetics with characters in vectors instead of typing them manually.

For example, I want to plot a subset of my data that was recorded at 22.4 degC.

```
isotherms <- {}
isotherms[[1]] <- data.frame(BHQ1 = c(0.0000000, 0.0000000, 0.0000000, 0.8985731, 0.8985731,
                                  0.8985731, 8.9857452, 8.9857452, 8.9857452, 44.9287262,
                                  44.9287262, 44.9287262, 88.4081250, 88.4081250, 88.4081250,
                                  132.6121875, 132.6121875, 132.6121875, 176.8162500, 176.8162500,
                                  176.8162500, 221.0203125, 221.0203125, 221.0203125, 353.6325000,
                                  353.6325000, 353.6325000, 530.4487500, 530.4487500, 530.4487500,
                                  707.2650000, 707.2650000, 707.2650000, 884.0812500, 884.0812500,
                                  884.0812500),
                         Em = c(1.4152309, 1.4838292, 1.5930397, 1.5539322, 1.4728192, 1.5890478,
                                1.3811580, 1.4405066, 1.3924398, 1.2632792, 1.2140788, 1.1582552,
                                0.9606513, 0.8988782, 0.9310566, 0.5657441, 0.5587639, 0.5590144,
                                0.2985498, 0.3017196, 0.3143352, 0.1771695, 0.1862939, 0.1672250,
                                0.1581635, 0.1944296, 0.1562263, 0.1403463, 0.1333305, 0.1357050,
                                0.1207715, 0.1224212, 0.1356236, 0.1317237, 0.1044410, 0.1423820))
```

I want my legend to say "22.4 degC" so I manually type a character that into the aesthetics, and I get a nice graph:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(viridis)
pallet <- viridis(2)
ggplot() + geom_point(data = isotherms[[1]], aes(x = BHQ1, y = Em, colour = "22.4"), size = 2) + scale_colour_manual(name = "Temp. (\u00b0C)", values = c("22.4" = pallet[1])) + theme_classic()
```

[Graph with legend](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mc25Z.png)

However, the code does not work if I put the character "22.4" into a vector, then call it to assign the aesthetics in ggplot2.

```
legend <- c("22.4")

ggplot() + geom_point(data = isotherms[[1]], aes(x = BHQ1, y = Em, colour = legend[1]), size = 2) + scale_colour_manual(name = "Temp. (\u00b0C)", values = c(legend[1] = pallet[1])) + theme_classic()
```

Does anybody know why I can assign aesthetics by typing a character, but I can't assign aesthetics by calling a character from a vector?

Comment: regarding your question, it has to do with `aes` being a quoting function - check out the [ggplot2 docs](https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/aes.html#quasiquotation) for more info on this

Answer (score 2):

The second plot is not failing because of the `colour = legend[1]`. It is failing because of `c(legend[1] = pallet[1])`. You can see this if you run `c(legend[1] = pallet[1])` in the console, which results in:

```
Error: unexpected '=' in "c(legend[1] ="
```

You can resolve this by naming the `pallet` vector beforehand, for example:

```
legend <- c("22.4", "30.1")
names(pallet) = legend
```

And then doing:

```
scale_colour_manual(name = "Temp. (\u00b0C)", values = pallet[1]) +
```

However, hard-coding an aesthetic is usually not the best approach, as it breaks the natural mapping between the data and the plot components. I'm not sure what your ultimate goal is, but, for example, if you have a list of data frames where each data frame represents measurements at different temperatures, you could do something like this:

```
library(tidyverse)

# Add an additional data frame to the isotherms list, just for illustration
isotherms[[2]] = isotherms[[1]] + 2

# Set names of each data frame to the temperature for that isotherm
names(isotherms) = c("22.4", "30.1")

# Combine the two data frames and plot them
bind_rows(isotherms, .id="temp") %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = BHQ1, y = Em, colour = temp)) + 
    geom_point(size = 2) + 
    scale_colour_manual(name = "Temp. (\u00b0C)", 
                        values = pallet %>% set_names(names(isotherms))) + 
    theme_classic()
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to pass `22.4` in the argument `labels` in the `scale_colour_manual` to define the label of your legend:

```r
library(ggplot2)
ggplot() + 
  geom_point(data = isotherms[[1]], aes(x = BHQ1, y = Em, color = "purple"), size = 2)+
  scale_colour_manual(name = "Temp. (\u00b0C)", values = "purple", labels = "22.4") + 
  theme_classic()
```

[image]

Does it answer your question ?

Answer (score 1):

I needed to do two things:

1.) Assign the color in "aes()".
2.) Pass the temperature into the argument "labels".

```
ggplot() + geom_point(data = isotherms[[1]], aes(x = BHQ1, y = Em, color = pallet[1]), size = 2) + scale_colour_manual(name = "Temp. (\u00b0C)", values = pallet[1], labels = legend[1]) + theme_classic()
```